# Conda activate.d and deactivate.d do not behave what I expect

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to modify my $PATH variable in conda by using activate.d and deactivate.d like:

In activate.d:

```
export OLD_PATH = $PATH
export PATH= "/path/to/something:$PATH"
```

In deactivate.d:

```
export PATH = $OLD_PATH
unset OLD_PATH
```

In **base** environment, `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
(base) $ echo $PATH
/home/myname/anaconda3/bin:/home/myname/anaconda3/condabin:/home/myname/bin:/home/myname/.local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/sbin
```

Then I activate my environment by:

```
(base) $ conda activate myproject
```

In the **myproject** environment, `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
(myproject) $ echo $PATH
/path/to/something:/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproject/bin:/home/myname/anaconda3/condabin:/home/myname/bin:/home/myname/.local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/sbin
```

Which is exactly what I expect. However, when I try to back to the **base** environment by using

```
(myproject) $ conda deactivate
```

What I expect is `echo $PATH` will output the same thing as it used to do in the **base** environment. However, what I get is:

```
(base) $ echo $PATH
/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproject/bin:/home/myname/anaconda3/condabin:/home/myname/bin:/home/myname/.local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/sbin
```

Notice that the first path is `/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/myproject/bin` instead of `/home/myname/anaconda3/bin`.

What's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Asymmetry Breaks Invertibility

The issue is that Conda is also manipulating the `PATH` variable and the order in which the scripts are run is not consistent with a proper inverse operation. Namely, the order of operations for both activate and deactivate is:

1. Update environment variables (including `PATH`)
2. Run scripts in `etc/conda/(de)activate.d` folders.

For this to be consistent with an inverse operation, one would need symmetry of operations. That is, activate should do (1) then (2), and deactivate should do (2) then (1).

Instead, what happens is that the `OLD_PATH` you save actually corresponds to *after* `PATH` was manipulated to activate the env.

### Workaround

Instead of trying to capture an `OLD_PATH`, you could track only what is added and remove that in the deactivate script.  For instance, something like

**activate.d script**

```bash
export MY_ADDED_PATH="/path/to/something"
export PATH="$MY_ADDED_PATH:$PATH"
```

**deactivate.d script**

```bash
# Credit for escaping: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/148899
escaped_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$MY_ADDED_PATH:" | sed 's:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g')
export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed "s/$escaped_lhs//") 
unset MY_ADDED_PATH
```

This seems to work for me on **osx-64**.

---

#### Debugging Tip

Conda can be a mess to deal with because it is a mix of shell functions and Python. However, one of the neat things is that the Conda entry point (e.g., `bin/conda`) has some internal functions that return strings of shell commands.

Specifically, one can inspect what would be run in the shell when running the command `conda activate foo`, using

```
$CONDA_EXE shell.posix activate foo
```

Similarly,

```
$CONDA_EXE shell.posix deactivate
```

will list out the operations for deactivating. This isn't all Conda does in activating and deactivating, but it covers most of it.

Comment: I have no /etc/conda directory.   At least on this system which is catalina.  Should I reinstall conda or anaconda again?

Comment: @RichMeister Note that this is not in the root `/etc` folder but under each environment folder (i.e., `$CONDA_PREFIX`). One often has to create it. E.g., with the environment active you can create the folders with `mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/{de,}activate.d`.